# How can I access the wordpress 5.7 API without being logged in?

Tags: php, reactjs, wordpress, api

I was working on an older version of wordpress and now we had to update to 5.7.
After that, access to **/wp-json/acf/v3/** was possible when I was logged in, but no longer with my react app,
which calls this URL for some data.

Every time I call the URL with my external script, I get an error:

**Request failed with status code 403**.

What am I missing right now?

Answer (score 0):

There was a function in the theme (in function.php) of Wordpress which blocked the call.